# Trimming duplicate characters with single character in string

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string, linq

This was a interview question - How will you efficiently trim the duplicate characters in string with single character.

Example: 
suppose this is the input string

> "reeeturrrnneedd"

The output should be:

> "returned"

I explained it by using splitting the string and loop through the char array, but interviewer does not convinced with the answer said this is not the efficient way.

```
private void test()
{
    string s = "reeeturrrnneeddryyf";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    char pRvChar = default(char);
    foreach (var item in s.ToCharArray())
    {                
        if (pRvChar == item)
        {
            continue;
        }
        pRvChar = item;
        sb.Append(pRvChar);
    }

    MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString());
}
```

Then I thought about Linq to object and use distinct but it will give incorrect output as it remove all duplicate characters and output will be "retund"

Can someone tell me the more efficient way to do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a solution with regex:

```
Regex regex = new Regex( "(.)\\1+" );
string result = regex.Replace( s,"$1" );
```

I'm not sure, if this is more efficient that your 'for' loop in terms of execution time, but it is more efficient in terms of developer work.
And easy to read, at least for people familiar with regex.

Comment: thanks @HeinzKessler,  I think he was expecting this.  If you can elaborate little about above expression it will be very helpful for me for further use.

Comment: I'm happy to explain it:
The "()" means: store the characters found by the expression in the brackets as a so called capture group. As this is the first (and only), it is capture group 1.

Comment: The \1 means: The contents of capture group 1, The + means: one or more repetitions.
The `regex.replace()` call replaces the pattern found , in this case by "$1", which means: capture group 1.
To learn and play around with regex, I highly recommend http://debuggex.com or  http://www.ultrapico.com/expresso.htm

Answer (score 4):

Your current solution could be more optimal if you

1. Pre-allocated `StringBuilder`'s capacity, which is possible in your case because the result string is at most the same length as the input string:

   ```
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s.Length);
   ```
2. Avoided constructing a char array to iterate through. The `string` class implements `IEnumerable<char>` so you might fed it directly to `foreach`:

   ```
   foreach (var item in s)
   ```

Answer (score 4):

## Race your horses!

Here is a pointer version using `fixed` and `unsafe` with pre-allocated result

```
unsafe string Mine()
{
   var temp = string.Copy(Input);
   var i = 0;
   fixed (char* pInput = Input, pTemp = temp)
   {
      var plen = pInput + Input.Length;
      for (var pI = pInput + 1; pI < plen; pI++)
         if (*pI != *(pTemp+i))
            *(pTemp + ++i) = *pI;            
   }   
   return temp.Substring(0,i+1);
}
```

## Results

```
Mode            : Release
Test Framework  : .NET Framework 4.7.1
Benchmarks runs : 100 times (averaged)
```

**Length : 100**

```
Name     |  Average |  Fastest | StDv |  Cycles | Pass
---------------------------------------------------------
Mine     | 0.003 ms | 0.002 ms | 0.00 |   3,935 | Yes
Dmitry   | 0.003 ms | 0.002 ms | 0.00 |   5,455 | Yes
Billy    | 0.003 ms | 0.002 ms | 0.00 |   5,706 | Yes
SAkbari3 | 0.007 ms | 0.006 ms | 0.00 |  19,730 | Yes
SAkbari1 | 0.009 ms | 0.008 ms | 0.00 |  25,029 | Yes
Original | 0.009 ms | 0.003 ms | 0.05 |   7,349 | Base
SAkbari2 | 0.014 ms | 0.011 ms | 0.00 |  41,027 | Yes
Heinz    | 0.040 ms | 0.037 ms | 0.00 | 131,196 | Yes
```

**Length : 1,000**

```
Name     |  Average |  Fastest | StDv |    Cycles | Pass
-----------------------------------------------------------
Mine     | 0.005 ms | 0.004 ms | 0.00 |    11,126 | Yes
Billy    | 0.008 ms | 0.007 ms | 0.00 |    22,402 | Yes
Dmitry   | 0.009 ms | 0.006 ms | 0.00 |    24,487 | Yes
Original | 0.010 ms | 0.008 ms | 0.00 |    27,334 | Base
SAkbari3 | 0.041 ms | 0.040 ms | 0.00 |   136,272 | Yes
SAkbari1 | 0.075 ms | 0.049 ms | 0.05 |   231,981 | Yes
SAkbari2 | 0.101 ms | 0.076 ms | 0.03 |   334,375 | Yes
Heinz    | 0.344 ms | 0.267 ms | 0.07 | 1,154,860 | Yes
```

**Length : 10,000**

```
Name     |  Average |  Fastest | StDv |     Cycles | Pass
------------------------------------------------------------
Mine     | 0.020 ms | 0.017 ms | 0.00 |     62,571 | Yes
Dmitry   | 0.056 ms | 0.046 ms | 0.01 |    185,538 | Yes
Billy    | 0.061 ms | 0.058 ms | 0.00 |    202,931 | Yes
Original | 0.069 ms | 0.058 ms | 0.01 |    230,297 | Base
SAkbari3 | 0.419 ms | 0.372 ms | 0.09 |  1,418,448 | Yes
SAkbari1 | 0.535 ms | 0.452 ms | 0.09 |  1,813,644 | Yes
SAkbari2 | 0.957 ms | 0.726 ms | 0.19 |  3,226,844 | Yes
Heinz    | 2.951 ms | 2.574 ms | 0.47 | 10,027,205 | Yes
```

**Length  : 100,000**

```
Name     |   Average |   Fastest | StDv |     Cycles | Pass
--------------------------------------------------------------
Mine     |  0.164 ms |  0.158 ms | 0.01 |    552,166 | Yes
Dmitry   |  0.498 ms |  0.467 ms | 0.02 |  1,690,471 | Yes
Original |  0.561 ms |  0.523 ms | 0.06 |  1,894,019 | Base
Billy    |  0.576 ms |  0.536 ms | 0.04 |  1,955,072 | Yes
SAkbari3 |  3.684 ms |  3.429 ms | 0.15 | 12,534,942 | Yes
SAkbari1 |  4.547 ms |  4.084 ms | 0.47 | 15,468,091 | Yes
SAkbari2 |  7.315 ms |  6.848 ms | 0.30 | 24,888,849 | Yes
Heinz    | 26.091 ms | 24.898 ms | 1.17 | 88,905,648 | Yes
```

**Length : 1,000,000**

```
Name     |    Average |    Fastest | StDv |      Cycles | Pass
-----------------------------------------------------------------
Mine     |   1.841 ms |   1.549 ms | 0.20 |   6,256,290 | Yes
Dmitry   |   5.237 ms |   4.740 ms | 0.27 |  17,808,335 | Yes
Original |   5.705 ms |   5.178 ms | 0.31 |  19,411,876 | Base
Billy    |   6.027 ms |   5.374 ms | 0.31 |  20,477,533 | Yes
SAkbari3 |  39.369 ms |  36.608 ms | 2.27 | 134,030,971 | Yes
SAkbari1 |  46.502 ms |  44.410 ms | 1.67 | 158,181,468 | Yes
SAkbari2 |  74.398 ms |  72.187 ms | 1.41 | 253,311,101 | Yes
Heinz    | 259.090 ms | 254.766 ms | 2.62 | 881,738,225 | Yes
```

## Summary

Regex sucks!

Comment: I dint use regx much, does it slow? I accept the regx answer as it loks very clear and unique.  I don't know how it works internally and what cost it takes to return the output.

Comment: @NeerajKumarGupta Regex is about 50 times slower then your original solution, and the bigger the string the worse it gets. Using regex in these situations is like trying to use a hammer to catch a fish

Comment: "Using regex in these situations is like trying to use a hammer to catch a fish" - what kind of "these situations" do you mean?
E.g. If the string was entered by the user and has a few dozens characters, nobody cares about performance. It's another story, on a web server with 1000s of requests per second, or a huge database project. So, to justify your statement, you should be more specific with the term "situations". Also, Regex can be compiled to IL code at runtime with the ´RegexOptions.Compiled´ option.

Comment: Do you really think that an interviewer expects an ´unsafe´ solution with pointers?
I am performing interviews a lot, and the interesting part is, whether the candidate asks the right questions back (and questions at all), e.g. about the context, the typical length of the strings, what the interviewer means with "efficient" etc.

Comment: @HeinzKessler woah, rant over yet? i use regex all the time, and have done for many years. but its commonly abused by young jedi. but for the point of this exercise who cares, i even marked you answer up. However in this case its about 50 times slower than everything else, and definitively not more efficient

Comment: @TheGeneral: My apology, my comments were not meant as a rant. I am no employee of "regex, inc.", so other solutions are totally fine for me. and overall, I fully agree. It all comes down to the question, what the interviewer meant with "efficient". Maybe I was a little provoked by your "regex sucks", but I think you meant "regex' performance sucks".
I was impressed by your work, providing thorough performance comparisons for all the solutions. Did you use a certain tool for it that produces the nice output?

Comment: @HeinzKessler, yeah its all good, no harm done, and i agree with what you say. also yes regex performance sucks in this particular instance when given 1000000 chars i should have really clarified that, as for the test suite, there is a good one called bencmarkdotnet, the one im using is my personal one i have been tweaking for a while, ill put it on github sooner or later, it does some cool things and makes sure each test is pristine

Comment: I would love to write the code in x86 assembler and beat all other benchmarks :-).

Answer (score 3):

Some suggestions:

- Don't create the `StringBuilder` until after you know the string contains at least one repeated character.
- To avoid resizing within the `StringBuilder`, use the constructor that takes the initial capacity and pass it the original length minus 1.
- Don't call to `ToCharArray()` as that allocates a new array and copies the string into it.

  ```
  public static string RemoveRepeatedChars(string s)
  {
      if ((s == null) || (s.Length < 2))
          return s;

      // Return original string if no repeated char
      int i = 1;
      while ((i < s.Length) && (s[i] != s[i - 1]))
          i++;
      if (i == s.Length)
          return s;

      // i is index of first repeat
      var sb = new StringBuilder(s.Length - 1);
      sb.Append(s, 0, i); // add everything before the first repeat
      char prevChar = s[i];
      i++; // skip the first repeat
      for (; i < s.Length; i++)
      {
          if (s[i] != prevChar)
          {
              sb.Append(s[i]);
              prevChar = s[i];
          }
      }
      return sb.ToString();
  }
  ```

Comment: This actually does well, however doesn't scale too well, better than most though

Answer (score 2):

This is a LINQ solution:

```
string s = "reeeturrrnneeddryyf";
var result = string.Join("", s.Where((x, index) => index == s.Length - 1
                             || x != s[index + 1]).ToArray());
```

Or another way:

```
var result = string.Join("", s.Zip(s.Skip(1), (first, second) => new[] { first, second })
                     .Where(z => z[0] != z[1]).Select(c => c[0])
                     .Concat(new[] { s[s.Length - 1] }));
```

Or another way: (using Extension Methods)

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> TrimmingDuplicateCharacters<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
    {
        using (var iterator = source.GetEnumerator())
        {
            var comparer = EqualityComparer<T>.Default;

            if (!iterator.MoveNext())
                yield break;

            var current = iterator.Current;
            yield return current;

            while (iterator.MoveNext())
            {
                if (comparer.Equals(iterator.Current, current))
                    continue;

                current = iterator.Current;
                yield return current;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then:

```
var result = string.Join("", s.TrimmingDuplicateCharacters());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Program using C Language
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char a[] = "rrrrreetttuurrneed";
    int i = 0;
    while(a[i])
    {
        if(a[i] != a[i+1])
        printf("%c", a[i]);
        i++;
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you should also explain your code to help future visitors

Comment: Nice answer, wrong language... and actually doesn't produce a result

Comment: It generates result as Expected ! Language doesn't matter, All you need is an efficient algorithm and an efficient programming language which produces better results.